# Names and algorithms for subgraphs with smallest neighbourhoods

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

I'm curious about some terminology for graphs and the existence of an algorithm.  Let $G$ be a graph and $H \leq G$ a subgraph.  Is there a name given to $H$ if $|N(H)|$ is minimum over all subgraphs of size $|H|$?  Are there algorithms to compute such a set rather than brute force?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by $|N(H)|$ you mean neighborhood of $H$, then this is close to the notion of [graph expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expander_graph).

As for your last question, I am positive, judging from inherent difficulty of calculating other expansion rates, I bet this one would be a hard problem as well. I am not sure, if there is nothing better than a brute force algorithm, but even if there is I wouldn't expect it to break the exponential barrier.

EDIT: Typos

Comment: Thanks, that will give me something to work from.  I don't have any votes left for today so if no one says anything else by the morning, I will +1 and accept this.

Comment: Cheers mate! If you need anything more let me know.